# Armature origin

Tags: game-engine, rigging, armature

I am making a shooting game . I wanted my hand and head to face the direction of the camera so it can look/shoot up or down.But when i face downwards or upwards , it result is not what i wanted . Have a look at this. [image]

[image]

This is obviously the origin problem . Have a look at the origin location.
[image]

I tried shift+ctrl+alt+c to set it to geometry but it doesnt work in armature.
Any solutions? Please help . Thanks and Over

Comment: the head and hands are separate objects ? how they are following the bones "parent, constraint "? what are you using to move the bones " animation, constraint "? if you can upload a sample file it would make things easier :)

Comment: I am sorry , I know this is very rude to someone who is willing to help but i don't really want to share my file for some reasons . I know where the problem is , just need to know how can i set an origin for my another half armature. Yes , they are both seperated using ctrl+alt+P. So that when i move my mouse , the hand and head will move instead of the whole body. As you know , they rotate around the origin . So if only i can set an origin for each of the upper half armature , the problem will be fix , but how ? Hope you can help me . Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it . Just remembered the solution. Enter edit mode and move the bone to your desire position for the origin.